# Will running a storage server in my rv significantly decrease the lifespan of the hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm moving into an RV/tiny house and I have a small storage server (appx 16TB) that I would like to continue to use. Assuming I keep the hard drives off while the RV is moving, will the vibrations from driving decrease the lifespan of the hard drives?

If I place the servers on foam padding similar to the padding used to ship hard drives, will the driving still decrease the lifespan of the hard drives?

Comment: @Hannu please also consider the second part of the question. Since hard drives are shipped daily worldwide, it possible that the packaging mitigates the effects of vibration while off. However, I don't have any evidence to suggest either way.

Comment: You could replace the HDDs with SSDs and then you could run the server while rolling.

Comment: @K7AAY I'd LOVE a 16TB SSD storage solution, but I'd need to save up for a _very_ long time to make that happen. hdd's are still more cost-effective if I can get them to work in this scenario.

Comment: _Joe B_, point well taken.  HDDs differ, so I would consult the drive manufacturer and confirm they always park drive heads at shutdown.

Comment: I suggest using soft drive caddies with rubber grommets, in a hard case.  The server should be bolted down in case of a crash, and the hard drives very securely held inside the server.  You can find some old articles on silentpcreview.com for ideas on reducing vibration , but since you're in a potential crash situation, make sure that the whole thing is protected against a crash, and that you have cloud backup of the most important stuff.  People are also more likely to steal from an RV than a house.

Comment: @JoeB Completely anecdotal, but years ago I transported two internal unpowered, non-SSD hard drives cross-country for under 48 hours and it effectively killed them. As already mentioned, have a good backup plan.

Comment: @Anaksunaman That's really interesting as hard drive companies are shipping hundreds of drives daily without any significant drive failure. So that I can learn from it, how did you transport the drives?

Comment: @JoeB They were outside their case with me in a personal vehicle. They were stored relatively safely in a small box by themselves and sustained no major jarring as far as I am aware. To your point, as well Christopher Hostage's, I am pretty certain it was an excessive amount of vibration that likely did them in.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming I keep the hard drives off while the RV is moving, will the vibrations from driving decrease the lifespan of the hard drives?

Mechanical hard drive heads are parked when they are powered off.  Since EIDE was introduced (late 80's) and possibly earlier, manual parking has not been supported or necessary for hard drives.  The head is not near a data area when the drive is powered off.

For best longevity and power savings, use 5200RPM hard drives if possible.

Your main concerns will be:

- Powercycling: Mechanical hard drives are stressed when powered on/off.  If you will be powercycling constantly that will affect lifespan to a degree.
- Unclean/unreliable power: Power such as that from a generator or weird power setups in RV parks might shorten the lifespan of most electronic components.  Invest in a power conditioner for your NAS.  Don't run your NAS on the same circuit as a refrigerator, heater, etc.
- Heat: Heat and mechanical hard drives are not friends.  Make sure the NAS is in a place with plenty of airflow and not stuck in some cabinet.

The following are disaster scenarios that have a higher chance of happening in an RV than other locations, also increasing likelihood of failure:

- Bad driving that isn't you: Your NAS could get destroyed in a wreck.
- Weather: Your RV may be more vulnerable to extreme weather events and could get destroyed in such a situation.  Your NAS could get destroyed in a flood, tornado, or hurricane.

Have a good offsite backup scheme/plan in place.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  The only suggestion I would offer is to have plenty of redundancy, so that a single drive failure won't be catastrophic.  Something like FreeNAS or other ZFS-based solution with RAID-Z2 or even -Z3 seems advisable.